# How to read nested array values without knowing the keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new in array. I wish to print out the values of all possible `[type] [label] [value]`. I wish to do like `"if there's a type with select, then display all labels with values"`

Below is my array.

```
Array

    (
        [product_id] => 8928
        [title] => Example of a Product
        [groups] => Array
            (
                [8929] => Array
                    (
                        [8932] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => select
                                [label] => Section
                                [id] => pewc_group_8929_8932
                                [group_id] => 8929
                                [field_id] => 8932
                                [value] => Section 200
                                [flat_rate] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [price_with_extras] => 0
        [products] => Array
            (
                [field_id] => pewc_group_8929_9028
                [child_products] => Array
                    (
                        [8945] => Array
                            (
                                [child_product_id] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 8945
                                    )

                                [field_id] => pewc_group_8929_9028
                                [quantities] => one-only
                                [allow_none] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [pewc_parent_product] => 8928
                [parent_field_id] => pewc_5d678156d81c6
            )

    )
```

The site is saying "
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So here's my so-called lorem ipsum :D

Comment: `foreach($arr['groups'] as $key1=>$val1) foreach($val1 as $key2=>$val2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for the same,

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($value, $key) {
    // check if key matches with type, label or value
    if (count(array_intersect([$key], ['type', 'label', 'value'])) > 0) {
        echo "[$value] ";
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hO0N4)

**Output**

```
[select] [Section] [Section 200]
```

**EDIT**

You can modify the condition as,

`if($key === 'type' && $value == 'select')`

**EDIT 1**

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($value, $key) {
    if($key === 'type' && $value == 'select'){
        echo "[$value] ";
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**

```
function search_by_key_value($arr, $key, $value)
{
    $result = [];
    if (is_array($arr)) {
        if (isset($arr[$key]) && $arr[$key] == $value) {
            $result[] = $arr;
        }
        foreach ($arr as $value1) {
            $result = array_merge($result, search_by_key_value($value1, $key, $value));
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
// find array by key = type and value = select
$temp = search_by_key_value($arr, 'type', 'select');
$temp = array_shift($temp);
print_r($temp);
echo $temp['label'];
echo $temp['value'];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/J9dgP)

Comment: But how do I check if [type] == 'select'? And what is the meaning of "[$value] "?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, if( $key === 'type' && $value == 'select' ) {
   echo "Value: " . $key['value'];
  }

Comment: Thx, but only the value "select" appears. I need to display the values of [label] and [value]

Comment: `[select] [Section] [Section 200]` Check first answer!

Comment: The first answer only outputs all the values. But it doesn't check if type equals to select. I tested it and it doesn't work. Or are you saying I should put two "ifs" inside the array_walk_recursive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198704/discussion-between-rahul-and-riwicaro).

Comment: @riwicaro See my EDIT 2 version of the answer. As per your expectations.