# How to call an associative array key in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array as below. I wish to check if the key [type] is equal to "select". If so, I wish to display the value of key [value]. How do I actually output the value of key [value] which is "Section 100." In the code below, it only outputs the value "select".

```
array_walk_recursive( $product_extras, function ($value, $key ) {

    if( $key === 'type' && $value == 'select' ) {
        echo "[$value]"; //This outputs "select". But I actually need the value from key [value]
    }

});
```

My array.

```
 Array
    (
        [product_id] => 8928
        [title] => Example of an Event
        [groups] => Array
            (
                [8929] => Array
                    (
                        [8932] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => select
                                [label] => Section
                                [id] => pewc_group_8929_8932
                                [group_id] => 8929
                                [field_id] => 8932
                                [value] => Section 100
                                [flat_rate] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
    )
```

Comment: I already know the "type". Now I just need to grab the rest of the data in the array inside the same dimension. FYI, I can't hard code the array like [8929] and [8932]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read nested array values without knowing the keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709172/how-to-read-nested-array-values-without-knowing-the-keys)

Comment: You already asked about this in comments to the answer you got on your first iteration of this question - so you should continue the discussion there, instead of creating what is essentially a duplicate still dealing with the same basic subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you`re able to pass these ids as parameters in that function you should be able to do something like:

```
$product_extras['groups'][$runtime_group_id][$runtime_field_id]
```

With this you should access

```
Array(
                            [type] => select
                            [label] => Section
                            [id] => pewc_group_8929_8932
                            [group_id] => 8929
                            [field_id] => 8932
                            [value] => Section 100
                            [flat_rate] => Array
                                (
```

Answer (score 0):

using array_map() and recursive(call itself)

call myfunction and send each value inside the array

```
function yourOuterFunction(){
    //your code....
    //your array $product_extras .......
    array_map("myfunction",$product_extras);

    function myfunction($value) {
        //search is array or not 
        if(is_array($value)) {
          //search array key and value 
          if(array_key_exists("type",$value) && array_search("select",$value) == true){
            echo "Condition true FOUND..";
            print_r($value);
          }
          //if not found then call itself
          else if(is_array($value)) {
            array_map("myfunction",$value);
          }
        }
     }//myfunction close
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very close. But the output is actually in a separate function (myfunction). How do I bring the output into the inside of another function? I tried creating a new array in myfunction and return that array but it doesn't show the actual values I wanted in that array.